# How to print NSMutableURLRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nslog, nsmutableurlrequest

How to print NSMutableURLRequest using NSLog ?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`.allHTTPHeaderFields` returns a dictionary with the header content:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
// {
//    "Accept-Language" = "en;q=1";
//    "Content-Length" = 190706;
//    "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+D90A259975186725";
//    "User-Agent" = "...";
// }
```

Or for specific field:

```
NSString *field = @"Content-Type";
NSLog(@"%@",[request valueForHTTPHeaderField:field]);
// multipart/form-data; boundary=Boundary+D90A259975186725
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try with

```
NSLog(@" %@", myMutableURLRequest);
```

Comment: request =  <NSMutableURLRequest http://112.152.8.204/Service1.asmx> This is wat am getting in logs. But I need to see the values added to it including header settings :(

Comment: @chaitanya: If you want to make sure you get the headers out, you need to edit your question to say so.  As it stands, this is the correct answer (hence +1 from me).

Comment: #chaitanya : i meant your NSMutableURLRequest values :)